# how to take list of pixel rgb values and turn into image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a code like this

```
from PIL import Image

def get_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("L")
    image_rgb = image.convert("RGB")
    pixel_values = list(image_rgb.getdata())

    return pixel_values
print(get_image('./test.png'))
```

and it returns colors of pixels to the output like this

```
[(r,g,b), (r,g,b), (r,g,b)] 
#^ this is what it would look like if it was from an image made up of three pixels
```

***remember that all of these are inside of the  `list(image.getdata())` list.***
im making a program that is going to change some values inside of that list based off of other things. I want to take the edited rgb values and turn them into an image and save the new image to a file

Comment: I recommend that you read the documentation for the `put` method of the `PhotoImage` class as a place to get started.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question.  You're using the PIL package to read the image.  Have you read the documentation for PIL on how to create images?  It's pretty simple.  Check out [Constructing Images](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new)

Comment: Treating images as lists is only extremely rarely the way to go in Python. What are you actually trying to do? If you are a bit more explicit it may be easier to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 0
y = 0
img = Image.open('img.foo')
pix = img.load()
for rgb in cr: # cr is the list of rgb values for each pixel
    x = x + 1
    if x > c[1] - 1: # < c[1] returns the max x value
        x = x - c[1]
        y = y + 1
    if y > c[2] - 1: # c[2] returns the max y value
        y = y - c[2]
    pix[x, y] = rgb
```

Answer (score 1):

`list(image.getdata())` provides you with a list of all pixels of your image. 
Let's assume that you have edited them, then you've got an `edited_pixels_list`. 
Following [Mark Setchell comment on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74036168/how-to-take-list-of-pixel-rgb-values-and-turn-into-image/76289984#comment134531718_76289984), you can just do:

```
image.putdata(edited_pixels_list)
```

Comment: Not sure why you would bother doing that - why not use the converse of `getdata()` which is `putdata()` ?

Comment: Sure, this is far more efficient than computing an ndarray with appropriate shape and using Image.fromarray() (as in my previous answer). Thanks a lot!